# HTML Editor problem in Ajaxcontroltoolkit in ASPNET

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I'm using Html Editor from Ajaxcontroltoolkit(Latest Release)in ASPNET Page. The text area of HTML Editor is shrinked when it is opened in Google Chrome.

Plz,somebody help me

Comment: Ajax control toolkit markup is broken in pretty much every browser but IE

Comment: Oh.. Wat is the solution for this to make the Ajaxcontroltoolkit to support in Google Chrome. It is working in other browsers like Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 1):

Set the "Height" attribute. (Mine is set to 234 pixels).

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set the height of the control using:

```
<cc1:Editor ID="txtMessage" runat="server" Height="200px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set these properties

```
Height="300px"  
Width="100%"  
AutoFocus="true"
```